# My GUI does not print anything at all

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

```
MyFrame(){
    String titel = "Rezept";
    JLabel label = new JLabel(titel);
    JButton abutton = new JButton("Abbrechen");
    JButton sbutton = new JButton("Speichern");

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    jp1.add(label);

    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    jp2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    jp2.add(abutton);
    jp2.add(sbutton);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(300,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

    public static void main(String[]args){
       new MyFrame();
    }
```

I just don't get it. When I run this GUI it doesn't print out anything at all.

I only get an empty frame. What am I doing wrong here?

(Code is in "MyFrame extends JFrame" class)

Comment: Normally you would add stuff to the [content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane%28%29) of the frame.

Comment: Could you post a compilable example instead of fragments?

Comment: Have you tried to use repaint or revalidate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will never see anything if you  call the method `setVisible(true);` before adding the JPanels...

change the order to something like:

```
add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
setVisible(true);
```

after that you should see something like

[image]

Comment: It totally says `setVisible(true)` in the posted code.

Comment: Ohhh I got it... I uodate the answer,,, you need to cahnge the order of the calling method...  call set visible ***AFTER*** you add all the child components...